# jQuery - select child of child of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to select the second div-child of the first div-child of a form.

If I have this html:

```
<form id="hello"></form>
<form method="get">
    <p class="search-box"></p>
    <div class="tablenav top">
        <div class="alignleft actions bulkactions"> </div>
        <div class="alignleft actions"></div>
        <div class='tablenav-pages one-page'></div>
    </div>
</form>
<div class="tablenav bottom"></div>
```

..I want to select the second child div of the "tablenav top" div inside the form. And then insert a div next to it.

This is apparently wrong:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("form div:first-child div:nth-child(2)").after("<div class='alignleft actions'><p>New div!</p></div>");   
});
```

**edit**: I should have specified a few more things - the very first form is inside a hidden div, and the form itself contains a few divs. And the last div also contains a few divs. Apparently this affects what sort of code will work.

Comment: div:first-child does not work, because div is second child, after p-tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $($("form .tablenav .alignleft")[1]).after("<div class='alignleft actions'><p>New div!</p></div>");   
});
```

**Edit**: Using eq(1) to get the second element in the array of jQuery objects is a much cleaner way.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("form .tablenav .alignleft").eq(1).after("<div class='alignleft actions'><p>New div!</p></div>");   
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="hello"></form>
<form method="get">
    <p class="search-box"></p>
    <div class="tablenav top">
        <div class="alignleft actions bulkactions"> </div>
        <div class="alignleft actions"></div>
        <div class='tablenav-pages one-page'></div>
    </div>
</form>
<div class="tablenav bottom"></div>
```

Comment: The fact you're creating a jQuery object, then taking a DOMElement from it and turning that back in to a jQuery object seems entirely pointless. Use the `eq()` function instead. Also, you want the element at index `2`, not `1`.

Comment: Yeah. Will switch to eq().

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `:first` as the `:first-child` looks at all elements within the container, not just the `div` specified. Also note that `nth-child` indexes are 1-based, so the `div` you're looking for is actually `nth-child(3)`. Try this:

```
$("form div:first div:nth-child(3)").after("<div class='alignleft actions'><p>New div!</p></div>");
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3jrbbp44/)

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("form .tablenav > div:nth-child(2)").after("<div class='alignleft actions'><p>New div!</p></div>");   
});
```

Check out this 
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1zxb25dz/).

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
$( ".tablenav.top div:nth-child(2)" ).after(your code..)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("form .tablenav > div:first div:nth-child(2)").after("<div class='alignleft actions'><p>New div!</p></div>");
```

worked for me